# how to get rid of cannot access a closed pipe exception in C#

Tags: c#, server, client

The method am using to send data to a server program is triggered by a button, The string is sent and I can print it out on the window of the server console but I get an exception on the client side that *cannot access a closed pipe*. The method is async but the string I sent to the server is immediately printed on the server but then on the client it says that it cannot access a closed pipe. Where did I close the pipe and how can I get rid of this error?
Here is how am sending data to the server

```
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Process the input entered by the user and check if the user exists
      var ip = textBox1.Text;
      var pass = textBox2.Text;

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
      {
          MessageBox.Show("A white space input is not allowed in either of the password/username fields");
          return;
      }

      // Make sure the server is running
      var processName = "ServerProgram";

      // Check if any process in the given array is running
      var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

      if (processes.Length > 0)
      {
          try
          {
              // The server is running, connect and authenticate the user
              using (var pipeServer = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "ServerProgram", PipeDirection.InOut))
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Connecting to the server");
                  await pipeServer.ConnectAsync();
                  Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server");
                  // Send the IP and the account name to the server
                  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer))
                  {
                      await writer.WriteAsync(string.Join("-", new string[] { ip, pass }));
                      await writer.FlushAsync();
                  }
                  // Disable the button after connecting to the server

                  // Read response from the server asynchronously (if needed)
                  var response = await new StreamReader(pipeServer).ReadToEndAsync();
                  MessageBox.Show(response);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show($"Error connecting to the server: {ex.Message}");
          }
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("The Server is not running, kindly start the server and try again");
      }
  }
```

Then on the server am using an infinite while loop to listen for incoming connections from clients. I did not close the NamedServerStreamPipe because I have used a using statement to define it which means the pipe is closed after the scope is exited.

```
static async Task Main(string args[]){
   while(true){
      await Task.Run(() => HandleClient());
   }
   static async Task HandleClient()
{
    using (var serverStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("ServerProgram", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
    {
        try
        {
            await serverStream.WaitForConnectionAsync();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(serverStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(serverStream, Encoding.UTF8, 4096, true))
            {
                string message = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (message == null)
                {
                    // Client closed the connection
                    Console.WriteLine("Client closed the connection");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(message);

                var userAndPassword = message.Split('-');
                if (userAndPassword.Length == 2)
                {
                    var user = userAndPassword[0];
                    var pass = userAndPassword[1];

                    if (dataBase.ContainsKey(user))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(user + " found");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("user does not exist");
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Invalid message format
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid message format");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) when ((ex.InnerException as System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)?.SocketErrorCode == System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.ConnectionReset)
        {
            // Client disconnected abruptly
            Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected abruptly");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]
What am I doing wrong for the server and client to communicate without a cannot access a closed pipe exception being thrown?

The exception occurs in the line below
[image]

Comment: First find out which line of the code throws that exception. You should be able to find that in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Fildor, this line is the one throwing the exception _MessageBox.Show($"Error connecting to the server: {ex.Message}");_ in the button event handler

Comment: That's the handling line. You need to look one step further. It should point to a line in the corresponding `try` block.

Comment: And I even have a suspicion: I would have to look it up to be sure, but I think it may be possible that disposing of the StreamWriter may also close the underlying stream. But that's just a guess as of now.

Comment: @Fildor, how do I get that line from the stack trace? am running both apps in hot reload format, means I should debug and catch the line that caused the exception in the try and catch block

Comment: Either put a break point in the try block and step through until you get the exception or if you have the full stacktrace, there should be a sequence of lines like "yadda yadda (line n) at yadda yadda (line n-1) at ...". In that you should find a line number that refers to a line in the try block.

Comment: @fildor, doing that in a few

Comment: @Fildor, it breaks on the same exact line where I set the break point, at line 75. But there is a dialog box but I cannot find the tab with the stack trace

Comment: @Fildor, I removed the try and catch block and got the error in the line where I am attempting to read from the stream reader, attaching a screenshot

Comment: @Fildor, looks like the pipe is already closed and am using it to open a new stremwriter object, help me revise the code so it works

Comment: As a least-impact attempt, I'd try to use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-io-stream-system-text-encoding-system-int32-system-boolean)) like this: `using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer, leaveOpen: true))`

Comment: @Fildor, Okay but also investigate my code and see why the connection or the pipe is being closed

Comment: @Fildor, your right when you say that the error is thrown by closing the stream, however when I add that parameter to the constructor of the streamwriter then the windows forms app becomes unresponsive

Comment: That's actually good. That means that the `ReadToEndAsync` is waiting for the end of the stream. To fix this, you either need to close the stream on the server side, or change it to `ReadLineAsync`.

Comment: Ah, wait ... it's async. That shouldn't cause unresponsiveness ... is it really unresponsive (in general) or just not displaying that particular response?

Comment: @Fildor, the code to close the connection from the server end was there but I am restoring it now

Comment: @Fildor, in response to your later comment, it does not show the response message but the program is responsive, maybe waiting for async to finish but its taking forever

Comment: @Fildor, changing to readlineasync

Comment: I agree with fildor, the original problem is most likely caused by the streamwriter closing the pipe. But are you sure a raw named pipe is the best way to do IPC? There are a bunch of protocols that take care of things like message framing etc, make it much easier to transfer complete objects between processes, and tend to be easier to use overall.

Comment: @JonasH, I have changed from using a pipe to a TCPListener which will let me send as many messages as I want to the server

Comment: I would still suggest looking into higher level protocols, like gRPC or MQTT. TCP provides a stream abstraction, and require you to handle all the low level details that higher level protocols take care of for you. See the [TCP FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html)

Comment: @JonasH, I will try them and compare the pros and cons

Comment: @JonasH, chat GPT misled me into using that code, AI is not ready to replace human programmers.